# Разбор библиотеки на "запчасти"

Tags: java, android

Весьма актуальный как мне кажется.
Есть библиотеки, имплементить всё подряд не дело, так как всё имеет свойство устаревать + зачастую нам не нужен весь функционал данной библиотеки.

Соответсвенно приходит на ум взять с этой библиотеки всё самое необходимое для себя. Но как "вытаскивать" необходимое, сам разбор не понятен.
Хороший пример, пытаюсь перенести некоторый функционал(typeFace) из данной библиотеки:
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Но вот с какой стороны подойти пока идей нет, надеюсь кто то поделиться с опытом, подскажет куда "смотреть".

Answer (score 1):

Гугл уже анонсировал человеческую поддержку шрифтов в новой студии (2.4), так что конкретно эту либу можно и не разбирать. А так - качаете её, изучаете как работает и из чего состоит и вырезаете нужные куски кода. Но, ИМХО, это бесполезная работа - проще использовать как есть - при каждом обновлении либы вам придётся заново всё делать если вдруг что сломается

Comment: google то анонсировал(3.0), но она появиться только в конце августа - в начале сентября + на новой версии, что немаловажно. Ну и как по мне идея автора наоборот здравая, либы устаревают, либо вообще не обновляются и если на проекте ты работаешь не сам, то потом может возникнуть много проблем + с заменой чего то на своё при "мёртвой" библиотеке придётся её самому воскрешать и в solo поддерживать.

Comment: Морозов, Ага, одно дело разбираться с готовой либой, которой миллионы пользуются и совсем иное - чужим самопалом, вырезанным криво, абы как работающим, с фиксами полупротестированными, а не командами разрабов и сшитыми с другими такими же франкенштейнамии из других библиотек. Эта работа просто не окупается.Спасибо, не надо.

Comment: @AK не будем далеко ходить) автору нужны только стили, по Вашему стоит запихивать целиком библиотеку?)) тем более такую объёмную. А если таких библиотек будет несколько?) Мы сейчас не говорим про общепринятые(милионные) библиотеки;)

Answer (score 1):

Вот Вам качестве альтернативы, вариант для раздумий: [downloadable-fonts](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/downloadable-fonts.html)